# iterating through files in a directory

Tags: python, file-io, time

My code supposed to get the last modified file and print in to screen while it keeps running until a new file is modified and it prints it to screen, but I keep getting an typeError.
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, int found.

```
import os, sys, re, time
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
from time import localtime

files = os.listdir('dir_path')

files = [f for f in files if re.search('.csv', f, re.I)]
files.sort

d = datetime.now() - timedelta(days = 30)
d = d.timetuple()

oldfiles = 0
newfiles = 0
for file in files:
    filetimesecs = os.path.getmtime('dir_path' + file)
    filetime = localtime(filetimesecs)

if filetime < d:
    oldfiles += 1
if filetime > d:
    newfiles += open(files, 'r')
    for k in newfiles:
        sys.stderr.write(k)
    while True:
        time.sleep(2)
        print"new: %s" % newfiles
```

Comment: Your indentation is probably wrong.  Could you please correct it?

Comment: no when i remove newfiles += open(files, 'r')
    for k in newfiles:
        sys.stderr.write(k) and put newfiles += 1 it prints the print statement at the bottom

Comment: I think @SvenMarnach is referring to the indentation of the `if` blocks.  They seem like they are supposed to be in the `for` loop.  Also, the logic you have won't do quite what your description says.  It will loop over all files once, then stop.  And to make it easier on us, what line is the error getting thrown on?  Finally, I think you mean `dir_path` to be a parameter, not a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things in your code that look strange. For example:

```
files = [f for f in files if re.search('.csv', f, re.I)]
```

Is this really what you want? The dot matches any character except newline. You probably need to escape it in order to get the desired behaviour, or you could just test with `f.endswith('.csv')` instead.

```
files.sort
```

This is not a function call. It should be `files.sort()`

```
filetimesecs = os.path.getmtime('dir_path' + file)
```

It is better to use `os.path.join()` to join directory paths and filenames.

```
newfiles += open(files, 'r')
```

The `files` variable is a list, not a string, right? Don't you get an error on this line?

Comment: @mintgreen: Ok, change from 'files' to 'file' then and check what happens.

Comment: this happens IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '21B8A1E8c.csv'

Comment: its csv files im trying to print im new to this but im catching on.

Comment: @mintgreen: You probably need to pass a full path to the open function. Use os.path.join().

Answer (score 1):

It seems like we do have a few type errors, I'll try to clear this up the best I can.

```
oldfiles = 0
# if newfiles is an integer, I'm not sure that it will be
# as helpful to you, I think you'd really rather have a list
newfiles = list()
for file in files:
    filetimesecs = os.path.getmtime('C:/tmp/' + file)
    filetime = localtime(filetimesecs)
    if filetime < d:
        oldfiles += 1
    if filetime > d:
        newfiles.append(open('C:/tmp/' + file, 'r'))
        for k in newfiles:
            # read the entire file and write it to standard error
            sys.stderr.write(k.read())

# I believe you want the while out here, after everything is complete
# it would seem that you would want the newfiles loop within the first
# for loop
while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    print "new: %s" % newfiles
```

Hope this has been of some value.

Comment: ok thanks but thers a problem it prints the filename and where the file is located in memory when it should be printing the contents of the file???

Comment: @mintgreen now the `sys.stderr.write(k.read())` will read the entire file and then write it to standard error.

Comment: If you want to print the contents rather than the string representation of the file, you have to get the contents.  As @macduff suggests, that means using `k.read()` instead of just `k`.  That said, I'd caution against dumping entire files to stderr as those could potentially be large.

Comment: it prints all the contents first and then it keeps printing where the files are located in memory which i dont want, i want to print the contents of the last modified file. ahhhh this is frustrating im new to this so please bare with me im still learning.

Comment: @mintgreen it's going to keep printing the string representation to the console (which defaults to stdout, basically) as long as you have `print "new: %s" % newfiles` there.  That's going to get the string representation of that object, which, if it is a file, is going to be the name + loc, or if a list of files, a list thereof.